# Trying to get the relevant details of all the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get everything

```
find all the tables, views, stored procedures, scalar functions, table functions, schema using sql query of a specific database
```

I actually wanted to create a autocomplete option but as of now my first step is to get everything in a list but not sure how i will get all of the above of a specific database

Comment: Can you be more specific? What tools/frameworks/languages are you using?

Comment: i add this code but ```SELECT ltrim(rtrim(s.name)) as object, ltrim(rtrim(s.type)) as type, ltrim(rtrim(s.status)) as status, 
ltrim(rtrim(su.name)) AS owner, s.type + '-' + su.name + '.' + (Case when s.name = 'P' then 'Stored procedure' end) as name  
FROM sysobjects s INNER JOIN sysusers su ON s.uid = su.uid 
 WHERE type IN ('U','V','P','FN','TF','IF','S','P')
 ORDER BY type, name``` - but i am trying to add a fullname of the type ```, but the issue is happening in the CASE

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You need to look into the system tables.  Personally, I prefer the standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views, but the information you want is spread out.

In SQL Server, you can use `sys.objects`, paying attention to the object type.  The place to start learning about it is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).